# ASP.NET MVC page slow Time To First Byte

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two views that I am refreshing every few seconds asp.net mvc. Every few views are refreshed since there is another program that is updating the database. It is taking a lot of time and it is random, what I mean by that is sometimes the first view reload time is slow and sometimes the second view reload time is slow. It is in 500ms or 50ms each for view1 and view2 or vice versa 500ms for view2 and 60ms for view1. I needs to reduce both the load time to 10ms. I have set the timer interval to 30 seconds and loading the views. I did sql profiler to see if the queries are taking a long time and it does not look like it. In dev tools TTFB time is showing as taking long and this is on my local machine with local webserver and sql. Please advise!

Thanks